# Difficulty understanding proof approach for a simple theorem.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I am new to rigorous math and so I have difficulties proving a rather simple looking theorem. The thing is I am not sure whether my work qualifies for a valid proof. Below you can see what I've done so far.

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ Suppose $a,b$ are nonzero real numbers. Prove that if $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$ then $a < -1$.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Basically we have four cases of different combinations of $a$ and $b$:

1) $a > 0 \wedge b > 0$;

2) $a > 0 \wedge b < 0$;

3) $a < 0 \wedge b > 0$;

4) $a < 0 \wedge b < 0$.

$\textbf{Case 1:}$ Suppose $a > 0 \wedge b > 0$. Then multiplying $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$ by $a > 0$ and by $b > 0$, we get:
$$ a^2 < 1 < ab < \frac{a}{b} ,$$
$$ ab < \frac{b}{a} < b^2 < 1 .$$
But then it follows that $ab > 1$ and $ab < 1$. Contradiction. Therefore, it is not the case that $a > 0 \wedge b > 0$.

$\textbf{Case 2:}$ Suppose $a > 0 \wedge b < 0$. Then, observing $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$ we see that $a < b$, which contradicts our assumption that $a > 0 \wedge b < 0$. Therefore, it is not the case that $a > 0 \wedge b < 0$.

$\textbf{Case 3:}$ Suppose $a < 0 \wedge b > 0$. Then multiplying $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$ by $a > 0$ and by $b > 0$, we get:
$$ a^2 > 1 > ab > \frac{a}{b} ,$$
$$ ab < \frac{b}{a} < b^2 < 1 .$$
Observe that $a < 0$ and $a^2 > 1$, hence it must be the case that $a < -1$.

$\textbf{Case 4:}$ Suppose $a < 0 \wedge b < 0$. Then multiplying $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$ by $a > 0$ and by $b > 0$, we get:
$$ a^2 > 1 > ab > \frac{a}{b} ,$$
$$ ab > \frac{b}{a} > b^2 > 1 .$$
But then it follows that $ab < 1$ and $ab > 1$. Contradiction. Therefore, it is not the case that $a < 0 \wedge b < 0$.

$\textbf{So}$, the three cases out of four lead to contradictions and the remaining one leads to the desired result. Does this make a valid proof? Or am I doing something wrong?

Will be glad to hear whatever feedback you can give to me.

Comment: Your proof looks good to me. If you break a problem into a collection of exhaustive cases, and show that each case is contradictory, or that it implies what you want, then you have proved what you wanted to prove.

Comment: Should show why $|a|>1$

Comment: @James So do I get it right that this theorem is correct and the only case it is actually correct is Case 3, when $a<0$ and $b>0$ because all the other cases lead to contradictions based on the assumptions we make in the theorem?

Comment: They look good to me.